# Why is $coNP\subseteq NP/O(1)$ and $coNP\subseteq NP/O(\log n)$ not same as $coNP=NP$?

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines

If $NP\subseteq P/log\implies P=NP$ why does $coNP\subseteq NP/O(1)$ or $coNP\subseteq NP/O(\log n)$ not implies $coNP=NP$?

Comment: If NP is [low](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_(complexity)) for itself then ​ NP = coNP . ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: yes thank you but that is not the problem here.

Comment: In that case, I'm quite curious what the problem here is. ​ ​

Comment: Trying to understand terminology in Consequences of the Provability of
NP ⊆ P/poly by Stephen Cook et al.

Comment: Do you understand why [NC$^0$](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:N#nc0)/1 has undecidable languages? ​ ​

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39318/discussion-between-ricky-demer-and-turbo).

Comment: Here, the weird thing is that $\mathrm{NP\subseteq P/log\to P=NP}$ holds, not that the other implication does not. It relies on self-reducibility: if $\mathrm{NP\subseteq P/log}$, the $\log$-size advice can be used to *find* a satisfying assignment to any given satisfiable formula. Now, we don’t know which advice string is correct, but there are only polynomially many possible choices. We can try them all, and we can *recognize* a correctly computed satisfying assignment. There is no analogue of this in the $\mathrm{NP\subseteq coNP}/O(1)$ situation.

Comment: For your input, the n advices produce n purported satisfying assignments. You check whether any of them satisfies the input formula. You don't care whether the advices are actually correct for other inputs of the same length.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I think I may be confusing things here. For problem input size $n$ we have $2^n$ choices of input. So we have $2^n$ possible SAT choices as inputs. We have $log n$ bits of advice and $n$ possible strings as advice. Assume advice $i$ for $i$ from $1$ to $n-1$ works correctly for $2^n-1$ choices of inputs. Assume advice $n$ is the right advice. If we use a random input with $n$ advice strings the odds of producing satisfying assignment is $1-1/2^n$. You have to check all possible $2^n$ inputs which is exponential.

Comment: For the third and last time: you don't check any other inputs. You don't care about any other inputs. Your task is not to find a correct advice string, but to find a satisfying assingment to the input formula (or rather to figure out if such an assignment exists). If an advive gives you a satisfying assignment, it doesn't matter if the advice is incorrect for other inputs.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek that clarifies. so L is in coNP/O(1) is 1 bit of advice helps you recognize x is not in L in poly time.  L is in NP as well does not help you remove the 1 bit. Right?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek : ​ ​ ​ The _reason_ for there being "no analogue of this in the" coNP situation, is that coNP is not known to be low for itself. ​ If P can perform the self-reduction, than coNP can also do so. ​ While self-reducibility is important for the conclusion, it's not the difference between the two situations. ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer I fail to see how coNP not being low for itself is relevant. The self-reducibility argument shows $\mathrm{NP}\subseteq C/{\log}\to\mathrm{NP\subseteq P}^C$, so the relevant difference is that coNP is not known to be closed under polytime Turing reductions.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek : ​ ​ ​ Unlike self-reducibility, coNP not being low for itself is **a** difference which does stop the proof from also working for coNP. ​ However, your _current_ point is correct; lack of closure under polytime Turing reductions is a much better description of the difference which matters here. ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​